# predicate for admissible ordinals

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

I was wondering if there is a characterization of "$\alpha$ is admissible" as a predicate, as I haven't come across such before. By definition, $\alpha$ is admissible iff $L_\alpha\vDash\Delta_0$-collection, but this doesn't actually give a formula for "$\alpha$ is admissible" because $\Delta_0$-collection is an axiom schema.

Now, it seems that the only way to formalize this would be to replace $\Delta_0$-collection (or equivalently $\Sigma_1$-collection) with a finite number of its instances, but I have never seen how this can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're wrong, because the statement $L_\alpha\models T$ is an *internal* statement, rather than an external statement. Here $T$ is an object of the universe, not the meta-theory.

And internally, the theory of $\Delta_0$-collection axioms is perfectly definable in the language of set theory, albeit via a very complicated formula. So stating that $\alpha$ is admissible if and only if $L_\alpha$ satisfies a certain theory, is in fact a single formula in the language of set theory.

In particular, Richter and Aczel's [Inductive Definitions and Reflecting Properties of Admissible Ordinals](https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/44063) (theorem 2.4) has a sentence $\sigma_0$ which is $\Pi_3$, where $L_\alpha\vDash\sigma_0$ iff $\alpha$ is admissible.

Comment: Ah, 'axiom schema' was a poor choice of words (I think?). Still, would it be possible for you to explain further (or give a reference) to how such a formula could be constructed, instead of just saying that it can, please?

Comment: Well, this is just the fact that $\Delta_0$-collection axioms have a certain syntactical structure, and you can just ask whether or not for every $\Delta_0$-collection axiom, $L_\alpha$ satisfy the axiom. It's as straightforward as that. Simply noting that all of this happens internally to the universe of sets, and therefore the whole thing is just one formula defining what it means to be admissible.

Comment: You need to be careful when doing this inside $L_\alpha,$ since the equivalence of your complicated sentence with the required axiom schema has to work even though $L_\alpha$ is not a model of ZF.  This isn't a problem, though, basically because limited formulas are absolute for any transitive set.  I think the easiest way of setting all this up is via a complete $\Sigma_1$ formula.

Comment: @Mitchell: But we don't define this internally to $L_\alpha$. We define it in $V$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I interpreted this as asking for a sentence $\varphi$ such that $\alpha$ is admissible iff $L_\alpha \models \varphi.$ I haven't looked at fine structure theory for a long time but, as I recall, you can find such a $\varphi$ by using a formula that is $\Sigma_1$-complete (uniformly for all $L_\alpha$) and then following what you suggested. If the OP was asking merely for a formula $\psi(x)$ in the language of set theory such that $\alpha$ is admissible iff (in $V)$ $\psi(\alpha)$ holds, then your answer is complete and there's no difficulty at all (it's just a long formula).